# json_encode prints data in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass Database table from PHP (using Object-Oriented approach) to Javascript using Ajax (`json_encode`) which I've done successfully. The problem, however, is that the values that are inside the $data variable are printed in my body tag with a huge whitespace after it.

Server Side:

```
<?php
require_once "Database.php";
Class Product extends Database
{  
    public function getAllProducts(){
    $sql = $this->connectDB()->query("SELECT * FROM product");

    while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
            $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
}

$p = new Product();
$p->getAllProducts();
?>
```

Client side:

```
$(function() {
    getProductData();
});

function getProductData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "Product.php",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successAjax,
        error: errorAjax,
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}
function successAjax($jsonarray){
    console.log($jsonarray);
}
```

Output (Note that body tags aren't being outputted):

```
<body>
    "[{"id":"1","0":"1","name":"john","1":"john"}, 
     {"id":"2","0":"2","name":"bob","1":"bob"}]"
</body>
```

Is there any way to prevent echo `json_encode` from printing data in HTML if all I want to do is pass it from PHP to javascript?

Comment: Could you share the complete code from Product.php? You have some HTML text remaining at Product.php.

Comment: You may put this instead: `return json_encode($data);` Also you may need to save  the returned value to a variable.

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I have edited the post to include the whole Product.php. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @enxaneta `return json_encode($data)` returns `Object "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: so you get an extra <body> tag only?

Comment: Try adding a `die;` after your echo. Also, be sure that your JSON is a valid one. What does the console.log outputs?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I don't get extra tags. The problematic part is the data that's being inserted into that <body> tag. I only want the data to be accessible in client-side but instead it seems like the `echo json_encode($data)` makes the data print in html.

Comment: That's my question. When you echo json_encode($data), does it carry a leading body tag? Could you share the complete output?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed The actual output is the array. However that is not the issue. The issue is that it's even printed in the first place. All I want to achieve is pass the array from server side (php) to client side (javascript). The problem though that the passed array also prints in html which is what I don't want.

Comment: @Mtxz adding die stops the rest of the code from executing. Also the console output is nothing. I'm pretty sure the JSON is valid since otherwise ajax wouldn't output it to the console, right?

Comment: As per your note <body> tag is not outputted. Then the rest is json string. Where do you see the HTML ?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed The issue here is that in addition to the returning the json string, something in my code makes the whole string automatically print on my page. Client-side receives the data from json_encode and I can output that in my console. All of that is fine. The problem is that it's also being displayed in my page. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: What is the rest of the code? Sending the json should be the end of your process as seen from your code

Comment: @Mtxz Well, the CSS stops working and all of the tags after the bodytag disappear. The array, however, is still displayed on my page.

Comment: I don't get it... Your Ajax request should be indépendant from the php displaying the page. One route/script for your page, and one for your async request.

Comment: @Mtxz Basically, this is what happens with die();

http://prntscr.com/kusr9q

Comment: I don't get what you are doing. As I'm telling you, the php script that return the json to the jquery Ajax should be indépendant from the php script returning the html. So one script display the html. In this html, the jquery will Ajax call another php script/url that returns the json. Then the jquery can print the json in the html or anything else.

Comment: @Mtxz But they are independant, are they not? The only interaction between them is the Ajax call and the `echo json_encode();`

Comment: So how a die; in the php script returning json break the html that is handled by another script?

Comment: @Mtxz Oh, thanks to you, I think I fixed it. The problem was the `<?php include "Product.php" ?>` at the top of the page. It seems like that was the part that made it dependant on the Product.php file. Thank you so much and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Nice. And yes the PHP script handling the ajax request does not need to be included in the PHP script handling the HTML. Glad you made it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to send out the json http header in first place on product.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Doing that makes the list.php (that's the name of my main page) open the page source. Basically, the page acts as if I pressed Right-click -> View page source